# Header set in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: magento2, .htaccess, apache2

I am adding below headers in .htaccess file but it is not reflecting in frontend.

I have done cache:flush and restart server apache.

I am getting - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKsoP.png in security headers.

Please guide me what is going wrong.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
############################################
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" 
Header set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=self"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"

# `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
# the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
# HTML documents and not for the other resources.
<FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>

## Prevent clickjacking
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score 1):

I have enabled mod headers in apache2.
It was disabled so it was not reflecting.

Please make sure mod headers is enabled.